# Microsoft Bot Emulator "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue", how do I debug this?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am having trouble with my MS.Bot.Framework + Luis + Azure

```
 await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => { return Chain.From(() => 
 new LUISDialog() as IDialog<object>); });
```

I have active Azure subscription, set up endpoint with subscription keys.

When running the MS Bot emulator I get error message "Sorry, my bot code is having trouble."  Using breakpoint in debug mode, I have worked out that the "new LUISDialog" is not being triggered, it seems to skip over it.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models;
using System.Threading;
using George;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

namespace Geoge.Dialog
{
    [LuisModel("*****", "*****")]
    [Serializable]
    public class LUISDialog : LuisDialog<object>
    {

        [LuisIntent("Greeting")]
        public async Task GreetingIntent(IDialogContext context, 
            IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
        {
            string message = $"Hello there";
            await context.PostAsync(message);
            context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
        }
```

Can anyone help me with this?  I have spend way to much time trying to debug and think I must be missing something simple.

Comment: Does it work when you test via the web chat in the bot in the Azure portal?

Comment: Is this a BF . 3.x C# project you developed locally or using web app bot. If you developed it locally, step through the code or add Console.Write statements. If you are debugging remotely, check the log, and also add debug statements  - might be Context.Write.

Comment: I noticed this `using George;` then `namespace Geoge.Dialog`  is one of these possibly a typo that may be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is strange is your initial code line:

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => { return Chain.From(() => new LUISDialog() as IDialog<object>); });
```

If you want to use your `LuisDialog`, you should not have this `Chain` here but rather something like the following:

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new LUISDialog());
```

Comment: chain "should" work here, but this would also have been my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue though the particular code snippet was correct. 
It got fixed after I **published my LUIS app on to Production**. Also the error on emulator said - Bad Request

I thought this might help someone in the future.